# how to call struts 1.3 action from java script

Tags: java, javascript, struts

i am using struts 1.3 for development and i am trying to call a struts action from java script my code is like below

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

        function callMyFunction(autoKey){

            var newUrl = '/AuftragTrace.do?autoKey=' + autoKey;
            document.forms[0].action = newUrl;
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }

    </SCRIPT>
```

when call this i got following error

Error 404--Not Found 
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found
The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass complete URL. Here:

```
var newUrl = '/AuftragTrace.do?autoKey=' + autoKey;
```

Probably should be something like:

```
// note the relative URL
var newUrl = 'AuftragTrace.do?autoKey=' + autoKey;
```

Or something like:

```
// note FULL url
var newUrl = '/AppName.war/AuftragTrace.do?autoKey=' + autoKey;
```

Comment: now it go to action but in action i can no get autoKey when i use String autoKey = request.getParameter("autokey");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if the variable 'autoKey' is having some value and that value is getting concatenated with the absolute URL (in the client side).